# Virtual List View Active Directory search using Novell.Directory throws LdapException: Unavailable Critical Extension

Tags: .net, active-directory, ldap-query, novell, virtuallistview

Same paging code works against a test domain controller, but doesn't work against another different AD domain that has same similar setup (Windows 2012 r2 based). `DisableVLVSupport=0` on both domains.

```
LdapException: (12) Unavailable Critical Extension
LdapException: Server Message: 000020EF: SvcErr: DSID-03140552, problem 5010 (UNAVAIL_EXTENSION), data 0

Error code: 53
```

Answer (score 2):

I was able to reproduce the issue on the working domain by setting `MaxTempTableSize` to a value smaller than the total count of users in cn=Users dn. It turns out that `MaxTempTableSize` should be bigger than the total count of the paged result. One of the main differences between the two Active Directory domains was mainly that the second one had a huge number of users.

Used `Ntdsutil.exe` tool to set the LDAP Policy property value.